# Convenient way to store sensitive information on Mac/iPad?

Tags: software-recommendation, security, password, encryption

Currently I keep an obscurely-named text file on my hard drive which contains things like bank account and credit card details, various passwords, PINs, and other bits of sensitive/confidential information. Obviously this is not too secure and I'd really like to keep this information encrypted and password-protected. I'm thinking of something like Keychain Access, but for small amounts of free form text rather than just passwords, and it would need to be quick and convenient to access (i.e. so not something like a password-protected Word document). If it could work on both a Mac and an iOS device like an iPad, and sync between the two, then that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 9):

I use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword). I a bit pricey but worth it. There are iOS and Mac OS versions. You have to purchase both. Where 1Password really shines is for website logins. There's a demo for the Mac on their site.

Comment: Thanks, 1Password looks very good, but the price put me off: $50 for Mac plus $10 for iPad makes it an expensive solution

Comment: +1 for 1Password. Great application and worth EVERY cent.

Comment: +1. 1P is an essential for me. The syncing works well between devices. You can also use web access if you do not have one of your devices to hand. I use that with Dropbox.It is worth the money. You can try the Mac version free for 30 days.

Answer (score 3):

I use Acrylic's Wallet, works well on iOS and Mac OS.

http://www.acrylicapps.com/wallet/mac/

Answer (score 2):

I use, and recommend [Splash ID](http://splashdata.com/splashid/) which I have found to be very user friendly. For each "item" that you create (say bank account) you have 10 different forms that you can name the forms and put in whatever you like as well as a comment section which allows for much longer amounts of text. It also work on iOS ($10 from the app store I think). It's normally $20 [but I found a coupon online for $10 off](http://www.retailmenot.com/view/splashdata.com).

I believe it to be very secure, and it handles copy and paste really well.

Comment: Splash ID used to be my choice of software back in the Palm days, but it hasn't weathered the transition to iOS well.  Also, the Mac app has a clunky UI.

Comment: For the record, I have totally gone to 1Password, and have completely loved it - no looking back at all. SplashID is less expensive - that's the only it has working for it now in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've had much success with Mac's inbuilt Keychain Access.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2013756/how-to-manage-passwords-with-keychain-access.html

Comment: Keychain is good for passwords, but I don't think it is any help with other sensitive data, such as credit card and back account details, PINs, etc ?